# Why if, in my web project, I don't delete the bin directory, I always obtain this error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http'?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am pretty new to **C#** and I have the following problem executing a web project.

Every time that I click on the **Firefox** button (inside Visual Studio) to execute my project and show it into Firefox I obtain a web page that show the following error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040) Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Net.Http' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: System.Net.Http | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Develop/EarlyWarning/public/Implementazione/Ver2/WebPortal/WebPortal/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\WebPortal\WebPortal\bin
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\WebPortal\WebPortal\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/a6cd0998/b670cdf3/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/a6cd0998/b670cdf3/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Develop/EarlyWarning/public/Implementazione/Ver2/WebPortal/WebPortal/bin/System.Net.Http.DLL.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\WebPortal\WebPortal\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.0.0
>   redirected to 2.2.18.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http,
>   Version=2.2.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/a6cd0998/b670cdf3/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/a6cd0998/b670cdf3/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Develop/EarlyWarning/public/Implementazione/Ver2/WebPortal/WebPortal/bin/System.Net.Http.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor
>   Version ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=2.2.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=2.2.18.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +218    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=2.2.18.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

The only solution to correctly run my project is to delete the bin directory inside my project, build it again and execute it. In this way it work correctly but next time I have to execute again the previous operation to avoid the previous error.

Why? What could be the problem? What can I do to try to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps your cache is messed up. You can find the `Temporary ASP.NET files` folder somewhere in the  %LOCALDATA% folder. I do not remember the path exactly, but it is safe to delete files in that temporary folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this on other browsers?

It looks to me a version issue.

What might be happening is:
Browser stores version of DLL in its cache, when you rebuild version changes in file and browser still thinks that this is old file and does not updates its cache and tries to find dll with old version.

And when you delete and rebuild, it creates new file so browser updates its cache and it works fine.

You can try changing properties of this reference and see if it helps.

Comment: Assemblies are not cached by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because of the System.Net.Http version. Is trying to find the 2.2.18.0 and instead of this version is finding the 2.0.0.0.

Maybe you should remove the reference and try to add the last version of the reference.

I believe that the last one is 4.0.0.0.

Then, rebuild and hope it helps ;)